# Microphone Specific Signal to activate interupt

Tags: c++, audio, microphone, avr

A heads up, i am very new to audio so please bear with me =)

I am trying to interpret audio signals into an AVR (its a classical myAVR MK2 board). Now normally, the interupt signal is always some kind of switch. So if i press this swich, go into that interupt.

My goal is to interpret audio signals via microphone into the board, and have the board react to it. My first question is, when sending the microphone signal, do i have to put it through the A/D Converter, since technically it is an anolag signal ??

My second and more complicated question is, how would i actually interpret the audio signal coming in?

For example, if i scream "GREEN" then what ever the programm was doing should be stopped, the interupt should be called and the green LED should come on. Now the mic is preatty much always on ... how do i control so that only if GREEN is said, the interupt signal is sent. I dont want him constantly going in and out of the interupts just because someone made some noise ...

Would i have to save "GREEN" as a bit-combination somewhere and compare the incoming signal with the saved bits ... or ??

Comment: Voice recognition is difficult, and doing it on an AVR is _reeeeally_ hard, but someone managed it with [uSpeech](http://arjo129.github.io/uSpeech/)

Comment: Unrestricted voice recognition is hard; you're dealing with tens of thousands of words, and whole sentences. This specific case (command recognition) is a lot easier. Still, vote to close as this is just too broad. It's missing basic understanding of audio, analog/digital signals, digital audio processing, pattern recognition and finally embedded development. Sorry, but that's 5 books you need to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some answers:

```
...do i have to put it through the A/D Converter, since technically it is an anolag signal ?
```

Yes, digital chips may fry when exposed to analog signals.
Be aware that you may have delay some time after starting the ADC before the signals are accurate.

```
how would i actually interpret the audio signal coming in?
```

Basically you have digital values coming in at a frequency.  You will need to store those values and then analyze them.  You must trade memory capacity/usage for accuracy.  The more samples you take, the better your data and results; but this occupies more memory.

You will also need to filter out noise from the signal and from layered sounds.

You may get some benefits from researching on FFTs.

You should compare using "fuzzy logic" because in the real world, nothing is exact; for example your voice signal could be +/- 30 counts and still be "correct".

Comment: Sorry, more samples does not necessarily improve the results. Noise filtering is not needed anymore (it was a problem with primitive pattern recognition algorithms which used patterns that are noise-sensitive). Fourier transforms are probably not capable enough, Wavelet Transforms do better.

Comment: Yo thanks bro. I guess the others are right as well, i am missing way too much basic knowledge to even begin this. However you gave me a basic foundation (which is kind of what i was looking for) Thanks @Thomas and others :) :)